# How Vuex hot update works?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on [Vue Freeze](https://github.com/BosNaufal/vue-freeze), Everything is working well, but I realized that Vue Freeze still can't do 'hot update' like [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) does.

Therefore, All the component which using the Vue Freeze state will be re-rendered even though we only change a small part of the state tree.

Example Case:

```js
var states = {
 
 user: {
   role: "admin"
 },
 
 todos: [
   { value: "halo" },
   { value: "hai" }
 ]
  
}
```

Every time we change the 'state.user.role', Vue will re-render All the component which use 'state' object. So, it will re-render my Todo List Component although I'm not changing the todo state ( 'state.todos' ).

What I want is, when we update the 'state.user.role' we do not trigger the re-render for the DOM that used 'state.todos' and only re-render the component which use 'state.user.role' only.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide~

Comment: Check out http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/en/hot-reload.html and the webpack docs https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html

Comment: I'm sorry @Jeff, I'm probably making a mistake in the question title. What I looking for is 'How Vuex Update its state' without re-render the whole app~

Comment: Vuex is open-source, for a question of this kind, your best bet is to dive deep into the source.